# How to display related products on the cart page (checkout)?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, checkout, cart

I have products added to the cart who have related products. 
My question: if it's possible to call and display all related products on the end of cart page (not in the cart).
thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is no built in way of doing this because the block that renders the related products depends on the 'current product'.
See `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related::_prepareData()`.
What I recommend is to create your own block. Here is what you need.
**You can get the related products for a product like this**

```
$related = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
       ->addMinimalPrice()
       ->addFinalPrice()
       ->addTaxPercents()
       ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
       ->addUrlRewrite()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
       ->setPositionOrder()
       ->addStoreFilter();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($related);
```

**You can get all the products in the cart like this:**

```
$inCartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$inCartProduct = array();
foreach ($inCartItems as $item){
    $inCartProducts[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

**You can add a block to the cart page by adding this in a layout file**

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference>
        <block type="your/block_type" name="related" as="related" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Put all these together and you should get your result

Comment: This is the correct answer; great point about `current_product`.